# selenium/selenium grid: how to post request to web server with different ip address

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-grid

i have to test a website that restrict total requests from same ip address. Is there any way to change ip address with each new request sent to web server so that server could not through exception that the current ip address is exceeding maximum requests? i don't know weather i could fix with change of proxy? i need to use it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to change the IP address of your local machine after each call to a server - this is currently impossible using selenium. If you are steadfast in trying to do this you'll need to look up methods of DHCP [release](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[renew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa393064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from c# or if you have the capability, giving yourself randomly created static-IP, all from c#.

Here's another link you might find helpful http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/8bf269bd-128e-457f-8c64-09834e995b59/

If you're distributing your tests, you might have even more trouble if all your test machines start changing their IPs - selenium will think it's lost connection to the test machine and bomb out.

Also, don't forget to change everything back after your test has finished (if you're using something like NUnit, make sure your settings are correctly reset in [TearDown])